# Получить строки датафрейма, которые не входят в другой датафрейм

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как в Pandas из датафрейма получить только строки, которые не входят в другой датафрейм?

Причём у меня ещё и набор колонок для них немного отличается, нужно чтобы отбор вёлся только по совпадающим колонкам.

Сейчас делаю так:

1. Делаю merge с опцией `how='left'`.
2. Поскольку во втором дф есть колонки, которых нет в первом, после мерджа получаю в результирующем дф эти колонки с пустым значением в нужных строках.
3. Делаю выборку по пустому значению в одной из этих колонок.

Но это выглядит каким-то велосипедом. Есть ли в пандас готовый метод для выборки только тех строк, которые отсутствуют во втором дф?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходные DataFrame's:

```
In [3]: d1
Out[3]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

In [4]: d2
Out[4]:
    a   c   e
0   1   3  11
1   7   9  12
2  13  13  13
```

Воспользуемся [параметром `indicator=True`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
In [5]: d1.merge(d2, how='left', indicator=True)
Out[5]:
   a  b  c     e     _merge
0  1  2  3  11.0       both
1  4  5  6   NaN  left_only
2  7  8  9  12.0       both
```

отфильтруем те строки которые встречаются только в левом DF:

```
In [6]: d1.merge(d2, how='left', indicator=True).query("_merge == 'left_only'")
Out[6]:
   a  b  c   e     _merge
1  4  5  6 NaN  left_only
```

и удалим вспомогательный столбец:

```
In [7]: d1.merge(d2, how='left', indicator=True) \
          .query("_merge == 'left_only'") \
          .drop('_merge', axis=1)
Out[7]:
   a  b  c   e
1  4  5  6 NaN
```

т.е. все решение будет состоять из одной строки:

```
In [8]: d1.merge(d2, how='left', indicator=True) \
          .query("_merge == 'left_only'") \
          .drop('_merge', axis=1)[d1.columns]
Out[8]:
   a  b  c
1  4  5  6
```

Comment: Т.е. специального метода для этого всё-таки не существует? Жаль, я думал что такая задача должна довольно часто возникать и наверняка для неё реализовали отдельную ручку :(

Comment: @Александр, если связь по одному столбцу то можно воспользоваться `.isin(...)`, если по многим, то указанный мною в ответе способ является, по-моему, наиболее идиоматичным

Answer (score -1):

По моему, проще вывести отрицание(~)

```
df3=df1.loc[~df['a'].isin(df2['a'])]
```